# Manga that involves a boy with cursed mechanical dragon wings whenever he is in danger

Tags: stealth-symphony

I cannot find the name of the manga.

- The boy ends up joining a mercenary group that has a talking Alligator as the leader.
- He teams up with a vampire girl, a robot dude with his robot dogs.
- In the last chapter I read, his team was stopping a slave trafficking caravan.

Comment: What exactly are you referring to with "cursed mechanical dragon wings whenever he is in danger"?

Answer (score 8):

This is definitely [**Stealth Symphony**](http://myanimelist.net/manga/66811/Stealth_Symphony)

- Boy with cursed mechanical dragon wings: check, the protagonist
- joining a [mercenary group](http://stealth-symphony.wikia.com/wiki/V%26V_Total_Security_Protection) with a talking alligator boss: check
- Vampire Girl: [check](http://stealth-symphony.wikia.com/wiki/Alice_Nijigami)
- Robot dude with robot dogs: Check, no link found :(
- Stopping a slave-trafficking caravan: Check, that's about chapter 6 - 9

[image]

Synopsis from MAL (taken from MangaHelpers):

> In a world where elves, dwarves, and invisible dragons live in harmony
>   inside a metropolitan city, Jig sets out to find someone or something
>   that can unleash the curse that he carries on his back. As he attempts
>   to survive in the city of Jinbocho, a city filled with fantastic
>   secrets and organizations, he encounters many powerful individuals who
>   set out to either destroy him or save him. Will Jig be able to
>   discover the true secret of his curse, or will it lead him to his own
>   demise?